Strange Variance Term for Normal Prior $w^2\sigma^2$
I've attached two screenshots, one with the question and one with the answer. It seems to me that the prior is wrong and it should include $w^2$ not $w^2\sigma^2$
I apologise for, including such a minor thing here, but this occurs in two different marks schemes across two different years. And it is maintained throughout the whole question. Is this some strange thing i'm not aware of? Thanks!


Adding the Whole Question Here
Here is the whole question to check if i am missing any hidden context.


Since $\sigma$ isn't even part of the problem statement, then perforce the answer is incorrect.  However, because your quotation begins with part (c) of the question, I wonder whether taking it out of its context has caused you to incorrectly to omit the definition of $\sigma.$

Thank you for responding, i know sometimes these forums can be funny about 'exam sheet typos' I have added the full question. Can you spot any important context i have missed?
